# Informix, NHibernate, TransactionScope interaction difficulties

Tags: nhibernate, informix, transactionscope

I have a small program that is trying to wrap an NHibernate insert into an Informix database in a TransactionScope object using the Informix .NET Provider. I am getting the error specified below. The code without the TransactionScope object works -- including when the insert is wrapped in an NHibernate session transaction. Any ideas on what the problem is? BTW, without the EnterpriseServicesInterop, the Informix .NET Provider will not participate in a TransactionScope transaction (verified without NHibernate involved).

Code Snippet:

```
    public static void TestTScope()
    {
        Employee johnp = new Employee { name = "John Prideaux" };

        using (TransactionScope tscope = new TransactionScope(
            TransactionScopeOption.Required,
            new TransactionOptions() { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
                IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted },
            EnterpriseServicesInteropOption.Full))
        {     
            using (ISession session = OpenSession())
            {
                session.Save(johnp);
                Console.WriteLine("Saved John to the database");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Transaction should be rolled back");
    }

    static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        if (factory == null)
        {
            Configuration c = new Configuration();
            c.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
            factory = c.BuildSessionFactory();
        }
        return factory.OpenSession();
    }

    static ISessionFactory factory;
```

Stack Trace:

> NHibernate.ADOException was unhandled
>     Message="Could not close IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection connection"
>     Source="NHibernate"
>     StackTrace:
>          at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.CloseConnection(IDbConnection conn)
>          at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.CloseConnection(IDbConnection conn)
>          at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Release()
>          at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect dialect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper)
>          at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
>          at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners)
>          at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
>          at HelloNHibernate.Employee.OpenSession() in D:\Development\ScratchProject\HelloNHibernate\Employee.cs:line 73
>          at HelloNHibernate.Employee.TestTScope() in D:\Development\ScratchProject\HelloNHibernate\Employee.cs:line 53
>          at HelloNHibernate.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Development\ScratchProject\HelloNHibernate\Program.cs:line 19
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>     InnerException: IBM.Data.Informix.IfxException
>          Message="ERROR - no error information available"
>          Source="IBM.Data.Informix"
>          ErrorCode=-2147467259
>          StackTrace:
>               at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection.HandleError(IntPtr hHandle, SQL_HANDLE hType, RETCODE retcode)
>               at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection.DisposeClose()
>               at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection.Close()
>               at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.CloseConnection(IDbConnection conn)
>          InnerException:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably work when you create the transaction after the session or, use session.begintransaction

Comment: transactionscope/opensession/begintransaction did not make a difference as the error was occurring during the factory creation in opensession. However, opensession/transactionscope appears to work as desired, though it seems backwards to me.

Comment: the session opens and closes the connection used by the transaction to commit.

Answer (score 1):

Is your Informix Database setup with Logging?   If it's not, transactions won't work at all, this is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I've got it working. The key was opening the NHibernate Session first and then creating the TransactionScope object within that.